# Trying to get directive contents before template applied

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a simple case here where I am trying to get the content inside a directive in my compile function.

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: compile
    }

    function compile(){

        return {
            pre: function(scope, element, attrs){

                // Get the current contents
                var elContent = angular.copy(element.contents());

                console.log(elContent);

            }
        }

    }

})
```

So, at this point the content hasn't been compiled, which is what I want. Unfortunately though it has had all of it's children scanned for templates and their templates replaced (e.g. there are  comments etc.)

Is it possible for me to take the content and interact with it before the templates have been replaced so that I can insert it back into the original element and let another directive (on a lower priority) do it's transclusion etc?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see child directives compiles after parent compile, so I think your question is not correct

[image]

Comment: Well, I'm logging it out in the parent compile function and I can see that the children have had their templates inserted but not yet been compiled, which are two separate things.